# Why doesn't AsyncTask executes when the execute method is called using an instance but without the instance works fine?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, development-environment, execute

```
//AsyncTask calling phase from OnCreate method
AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsynTask();

asyncTask.execute();
//doesn't work!!!!//

new AsyncTask().execute();
//works fine!!!//
```

while calling the first way it is showing errors but as soon as I change it to the next way it works perfectly fine....Why?

Comment: According to the source code for `AsyncTask`, attempting to call the constructor directly will throw an exception.  Please read the documentation to learn how to use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot..:)